# How do I show an image content into ScrollPane with binding?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I've some images into the project folder. Each image has a name. For example: a, aa, aba etc. I want to show the related image into ScrollPane when it matches an image name typed into the TextField.

I did similar one by using the following codes:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/imran/dict/meaning/"+txt.getText());
Image image = new Image(url.toExternalForm());
showinScroll.setContent(new ImageView(image));
```

But this is not what I wanted. It works when I type some text and press enter. But I want to show the related image into ScrollPane when it matches an image name while typing into the TextField. No need to press enter after typing the full text.

I succeeded to do the same thing for ImageView using binding. Here is the following code:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) 
{
    showinScroll.imageProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> 
    {
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/imran/dict/meaning/"+grabTxt.getText());
        Image image = new Image(url.toExternalForm());          
        return image;           
    },grabTxt.textProperty()));
}
```

I want to do the same thing for ScrollPane not for ImageView. How to do it?

Comment: Do you want to set a background image to ScrollPane? Ideally, images are adding to the ImageView which in turn is added to the Layout.

Comment: I want to do the same as I did with setContent() method. showinScroll.setContent(new ImageView(image));

Actually my purpose is to show the image into scrollpane.

Comment: Does the ScrollPane already exist when you are typing the text into the TextField? If yes, then why can't you just add the ImageView into the ScrollPane when you are initializing and then just set the Image in it using the same binding on imageProperty() of ImageView?

Comment: Yes I thought to do that but the problem is ImageView doesn't show the default image resolution, it automatically get fitted to the size of ImageView. But a ScrollPane shows an image with its default resolution, thats why when a bigger image is opened it can be viewed by scrolling the bar. This is why I want to show the image into a ScrollPane.

Comment: I am sure if you don't set the `fitWidth` or `fitHeight` of the ImageView, it won't change the image size. If you can provide us  with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and what exactly doesn't work in it, we can provide you faster solution.

Comment: Check out this [MCVE](https://gist.github.com/TheItachiUchiha/aeee15daf6eb8250cbe3). The TextField already has the URL with a "g" missing to the jpg. Complete it by adding a **g** at the end. Wait for sometime for the image to load. If you are looking for something else then add it to comment :)